# Do all Pokemon B/W Wifi features work with WPA2?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, wifi, nintendo-dsi

I've learned that original (and Lite) Nintendo DS systems do not support WPA/WPA2 Wifi encryption, but the newer hardware (DSi, 3DS) does.

I've also learned that this only applies to newer games, and that older games require WEP, even on newer systems.

Finally, I've learned that Pokemon Black and White **do**, nominally, support WPA2 encryption.

However, I've had a few sources tell me that this only applies to a subset of features, and to battle or trade over Nintendo WFC I'll have to fall back to WEP.

Can someone either confirm that this is the case and tell me what I won't be able to do over WPA2, or set me straight and confirm (via experience, please) that **everything** works over WPA2?

Sadly I don't have a DSi or I'd puzzle this out myself, but this is a deciding factor in whether I get a 3DS at launch or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I spent a half hour a few nights ago wrestling with my router in attempt just to get my DS Lite to connect to WEP.  I wish you luck.

Comment: @StrixVaria: You have no idea how amazed I was when my Wii only took three attempts to connect to my network. Nintendo just doesn't "get" online, it seems.

Comment: There is, at the very least, no *logical* reason why you would have to fall back - the WPA encryption doesn't exist outside of your wireless network, and it seems like strange coding if any part of the game bypassed the Wifi routines they need to have in place to support WPA at all via the DSi enhancement. Having said that, I also do not have a DSi, so I can't test it either.

Comment: @Michael A significant amount of the WFC stuff, stuff that should be part of the OS appears to be on the game carts. Eg You need to have a game in to connect to a network.

Comment: @Macha: I'm completely aware that this stuff is on the cartridges themselves - the DS doesn't *have* anything that could really be classified as an OS, so it has to be - but they don't write every line of code from scratch for every game. There's a library of routines which gets compiled in to do these things, and that includes at least the fundamental parts of the WiFi communication. Since the games are DSi enhanced, they would necessarily have used a DSi-capable version of the library, giving WPA(2) support for everything unless they bypassed that library somewhere (which would be strange).

Comment: The good news is that if this is unanswered in a week, I'll be able to answer it myself (decided to go for the 3DS after all).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just did a random matchup with someone in Japan on my new 3DS. Not sure what problems other people might be having, but the newer hardware seems to work fine with WPA2.

Will update if I actually have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there should be no problem using WPA2 with DSi (XL)/3DS. Since the WFC isn't online yet, I haven't been able to test properly, but it seems to connect properly.

Answer (score 1):

i can help anyone that can set you up to connect to your wireless router on WPA2/WPA its not very hard seriously and its easy to do since i just bought the game last night and on  3rd gym and my wireless is WPA2/WPA ands its works Perfect if you need any suggestions how to get it DSi XL  Folllow These Instructions below

1. Go to your System Setting on your DS
2. Go To Internet Type your Security password in
3. click Connection  then Go To your Advance Option you should see thing Called Wi-fi Protection Setup on your Nintendo DSi XL  Click that  (i know some regular access won't be compatible because you have to set them up on your own from your Router)

   4. Click the Pin Number and Write the Number and just leave it on just right there for sec
   5. Now The Computer You need to go to your Wireless router Home Site like mine is like for example Belkin i would have to type router/ and enter to bring out my belkin
   6. Now when you have your router on your page you need to click Wi-fi Prtotection Setup to bring up the page.
   7. You Need to Find Thing Called Client Device Pin ( You will need to Enter the Pin Number on your Nintendo DSi XL if your using WPA2/WPA and click Enroll and Wait 2 Minutes after that Click the Push connection after 2 minutes and the connection Should Go Through on WPA2/WPA and it should work on your Pokemon black or white

if you don't know your wpa2/wpa you should be automatically can log in without knowing it since i know most routers will let you to login to leave them blank hopefully this helps with WPA2/WPA

Comment: This question talks about the DS, not the DSi. The DS doesn't have that option in a way compatible with WPA2/WPA.

Answer (score -2):

I have tested on my 3DS and did not have any problems doing a random matchup over WPA2.

Comment: Hey, achappell, welcome to the site. This answer just says what Sapph already stated in his answer, try to add new info in your answers.